# How To Resolve IP Addresses To Domain Names?

Tags: ip-address, hostname, domain-name, rdns

I know it is possible to resolve IP addresses to host names but can IPs be resolved to domain names?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you can (sometimes) resolve an IP Address back to a hostname.

Within DNS, an IP Address can be stored against a `PTR` record.  You can use `nslookup` to resolve both hostnames and IP addresses, though use of `nslookup` has been deprecated for quite some time.

For best results, you should really get a hold of the `dig` tool.  If you're a linux user, this is available as part of `dnsutils` (debian), or similar package.  If you're a windows user, you can follow instructions such as [these](http://unroutable.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-install-dig-for-windows.html) to install `dig`.

You can then do:

```
dig A <hostname>
```

To lookup the IPv4 address for a host, or:

```
dig AAAA <hostname>
```

To lookup the IPv6 address for a host, or:

```
dig PTR ZZZ.YYY.XXX.WWW.in-addr.arpa.
```

To lookup the hostname for IPv4 address `WWW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ` (note the octets are reversed), or:

```
dig PTR b.a.9.8.7.6.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa.
```

To get the hostname for the IPv6 address 2001:db8::567:89ab.

Comment: Just figured it'd be good to mention: When you ask a DNS server to resolve an IP to a hostname, the technical name for it is a reverse lookup.

Comment: Indeed - the reverse lookup is achieved via a `PTR` Resource Record, PTR being shorthand for `pointer`.

Comment: What's wrong with `dig -x <ipaddress>`? On my Linux system, it speaks both IPv4 and IPv6. `dig -x 169.254.0.1` and `dig -x fe80::1`.

Comment: Additionally, with both nslookup and dig, enabling trace mode will sometimes give you clues even when an IP address has no exact PTR record. Using dig, add `+trace` to the command line. With nslookup, at least on Windows, it's `set debug` in its command mode before issuing the lookup.

Comment: Probably the most common use for a PTR record is with e-mail. The receiving e-mail server usually checks to make sure that the PTR record matches the domain trying to send, and if not, it will drop it.

Comment: Good answer. The question however sounds like someone who wants to know who is responsible for the IP in question. In that case, I would recommend a WHOIS tool, "whois a.b.c.d" to figure out who owns the address range.

Comment: @Michael, agreed.

Comment: For windows, I seem to remember using `ping -a 192.168.0.1` and getting a name back.  Can anyone on Windows see if that works for external IP's?

Comment: @hyperslug, ping's `-a` option is listed as `Resolve addresses to hostnames` on Win7 at least, so I don't see why it wouldn't work. However, `nslookup` or even better `dig` are actually *meant* for things like this. `Ping` isn't.

Comment: "use of nslookup has been deprecated for quite some time" Wait, what? [citation needed]

Comment: @TheLQ: I quote from the [BIND 9.4 Administrators Reference Manual](http://www.isc.org/software/bind/documentation/arm94), "Due to its arcane user interface and frequently inconsistent behavior, we do not recommend the use of nslookup. Use dig instead.". In many cases, use of `nslookup` also results in "`nslookup` is deprecated and may be removed from future releases. Consider using the `dig` or `host` programs instead".  [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nslookup+deprecated&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari) could easily have informed you of this had you cared to look.

Answer (score 20):

`nslookup <ipaddress>` or `nslookup <hostname>`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nslookup`, `dig`, or other network tool to possibly get *a* domain name for an IP address, but it's not necessarily going to be the one you're expecting.

Unlike normal DNS lookups, where many names can resolve to a single IP address, reverse DNS lookups can only resolve to a single name, and that's handled by whomever controls the reverse DNS information for the IP block in question.  Nobody else can set up a `PTR` record on a random IP address block.  This is in contrast to "normal" DNS lookups, where anyone can set up a domain name and create `A` records pointing at whatever IP addresses they'd like.

[This ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/135247/reverse-dns-lookup-from-the-command-line/135250#135250) has a bit more info on this topic.

My point is that just because you can do it doesn't mean that you'll get what you're expecting or that it will be useful.

Comment: +1: This had to be said. Often for well-known internet sites where the `A` record and the `PTR` record are both under control of the same person, the `PTR` record still refers to some internal machine name. The `PTR` record may also be nonexistant, for example if you try to `dig www.google.com` then `dig -x` one of the IP addresses that `www.google.com` maps to.

Comment: It should be said that a common situation is shared servers, where the reverse lookup will be the domain assigned by whatever company owns the server. Or, for shared IPs, whatever company owns the ISP. for example, if you do a reverse lookup on a website's IP, you might get something odd like "host123.somecompany.com". You're probably seeing a shared server. If you do a reverse on a random IP, you might see something like "c-12-34-56-78.hsd1.or.comcast.net". This is an IP belonging to comcast.net, an ISP, so it must be some random home user.

Comment: There is no technical limit on how many PTR records a single IP address can resolve to; the one PTR is just a convention (also security/privacy reasons).

Answer (score 3):

`dig` has the `-x addr` option:

> Reverse lookups -- mapping addresses to names -- are simplified by the `-x` option.  `addr` is an IPv4 address in dotted-decimal notation, or a colon-delimited IPv6 address. When this option is used, there is no need to provide the `name`, `class` and `type` arguments

For example:

`dig -x 82.165.8.211`

As an aside: the IP address was in the journalctl log of an ARTIK 710 dev board, and I thought it had been hacked. I couldn't remember the `dig` option to do this without using the tedious PTR method, but then I saw [Michael](https://superuser.com/users/53590/michael-kj%c3%b6rling)'s [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/315687/how-to-resolve-ip-addresses-to-domain-names/1230160#comment337932_315697).

And the manpage for `dig` just mentions it in passing; I didn't even notice it until I found the answer here and went back and searched for it.

p.s. the address resolved to ipv4.connman.net, and then I found it; I wasn't hacked.

```
[root@artik ~]# grep -r '\<ipv4.connman.net\>' /etc /usr/bin /usr/sbin
Binary file /usr/sbin/connmand matches
```

the log entries that caused concern were:

```
Jul 15 04:41:11 artik connmand[1870]: wlan0 {add} route 82.165.8.211 gw 192.168.251.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
Jul 15 04:41:12 artik connmand[1870]: wlan0 {del} route 82.165.8.211 gw 192.168.251.1 scope 0 <UNIVERSE>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to "resolve" IP-addresses to hostnames is possible using the [bing](http://www.bing.com/) search engine. If the host runs a public webserver and some sites served by the host are indexed, you can query it using the `ip:` prefix.

Just enter [`ip:64.34.119.12`](http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3a64.34.119.12) into the search form to get a list of hostnames behind that ip.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the host name either IPv4 or IPv6 address by making use of the gethostbyaddr() function in sockets.

Link: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/gethostbynameman.html

Regards,
SSuman185

Answer (score 0):

How about host? I use it on a daily basis at work

```
#host speakeasy.net
speakeasy.net has address 69.17.117.156
speakeasy.net mail is handled by 5 mx.speakeasy.net.
speakeasy.net mail is handled by 10 mx01.speakeasy.net.
speakeasy.net mail is handled by 15 mx02.speakeasy.net.

#host 69.17.117.156
156.117.17.69.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer www.speakeasy.net.
```

Comment: But this is for Linux.

Comment: @boris_yo, here is one for windows: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Misc-Networking-Tools/Host.shtml - I know there is a better one out there, I just need to find it.